# Updating sub properties of Partial object

Tags: typescript

I have a Partial object which has potentially undefined sub-properties I would like to update.

```
interface Foo {
    data: string
    otherData: string
}
interface Bar {
    foo: Foo
}
interface Baz {
    bar: Bar
}

let a: Partial<Baz> = {}

//... Desired action:
a.bar.foo.data = 'newData'
```

This is not allowed, because the properties are potentially undefined. One "solution" to this is the following monstorsity;

```
a = {
    ...a,
    bar: {
        ...a?.bar,
        foo: {
            ...a?.bar?.foo,
            data: 'newData'
        }
    }
} as Partial<Baz>
```

Is there some more elegant way of achieving this?

[ts playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIAmcYcAXMgM5hSgDm+h6YAFtACKkXW0O4BfXKEixEKAEJwoOJgRiZKGdIOHho8JMikAvWYWQAjaZSlRVuADYQwyHgAVpYYHEsAeXQD5kAXhxDrW0NKRyhnVw84HW8-bGMoSmwFdETkFnYoLjJKAHJIGhyBIrsqZFDw9y9cXAR0ECp0awA6S3R6AAo4AEoauobm1o7DHqsbZBAIAHcsuF9kHIaAWxQaOhB6HOrZ2LlkJv24ABpd+MTdg32muAB+JvjjgwNks8fXvYPb+Nvkh7eDEmy4ymM3OhCEBiEAhKZScLkqUU81UMczwF32hl+BFO+jel0Mn2kmMezxxfwIeIJUG+mCJfwBPAm024oII4LBgmh5ThkWi1Vq9UaEBabU6PX5-SFg3aw2quAA9HLkBwIFRgFAIERqI0AK7OOqHLXLNgMajARbASzSZBgLDGqgAbnlirgd2kTWSTXpc0ZIIVdkp1PQty9fh9zKAA)

Comment: Note the partial is irrelevant; all `Partial` does is make all props of the root object optional, but in this case they already are.

Comment: True, in my production case, the properties are not optional, but the incomming objects are.

Comment: Then why the focus on partial? Give an example that actually reflects what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the nullish coallecesing assignment operator (`??=`) to do this:

```
((a.bar ??= {}).foo ??= {}).data = 'newData';
```

Comment: Sorry for not marking this as the solution yet, but I'm having some issues being able to use this. I'm getting `Property 'foo' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Bar'`, and error `Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Bar | {}'.` I can solve this by writing `((((a.bar as Partial<Bar>) ??= {}).foo as Partial<Foo>) ??= {}).data = 'newData';`